# Common exceptions highlighted as Unresolved Reference in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

My project compiles and builds well. I can even generate working apk, yet my Android Studio marks common Exception classes (IllegalStateException, NPE, Exception etc.) in red and shows them as "Unresolved reference". What's wrong? How can I fix it?